# Letra repetida contenida dentro de vector de String Javascript

Tags: javascript

Buenas tardes, cómo podría hacer para que dentro de un array de String pueda detectar que letras se repiten dentro de ellos mismos

Por ejemplo, si tengo el vector contenido= ["hola","piano","triangulo"];
pueda retornarme un array resultado=["o","a"]; los cuales son las 3 letras que se encuentran presentes en cada String, he intentado con for pero no me sale, alguna ayuda por favor, gracias

Este código intenté:

```
    var datos= ["hola", "piano", "triangulo"];
    var resultado[];


    for(int i=0;i<datos.length;i++){
    char A[] = datos[i];
        var a=0;
        while(a<datos.length){
            char B[] = datos[i+1];

            for(int j=0;j<A.length;j++){
                if(A[j]==B[a]){
                    resultado.push(A[j]);
                }
            }
            a++;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Listo, ahí es lo que tengo

Answer (score 3):

La verdad es que no consigo seguir tu código.

Además la sintaxis `char variable[]` no sirve para declarar un array de caracteres en javascript.
Javascript es un lenguaje no tipado, no se indica el tipo de la variable, por lo que éstas pueden contener cualquier tipo de valor.

Aquí te dejo una posible solución:

```js
function repetidos(palabras){
  // Si no se pasa array o se pasa uno de longitud 0 devuelve null
  if (!palabras || !palabras.length) return null;
  // Cogemos los caracteres de la primera palabra
  var first = contenido[0].split('');
  // Obtenemos los caracteres de la primera palabra que están
  // presentes en todas
  return first.filter(
    (c, i) =>
      first.indexOf(c) === i // es la primera ocurrencia del carácter
      && contenido.every(x=> x.indexOf(c) >= 0)); // y está en todas
}

var contenido= ["hola","piano","triangulo"];

console.log(repetidos(contenido));
```

El código coge la primera palabra y la convierte a un array de caracteres llamando al método `split` con una cadena vacía.

Luego utiliza el método `filter` para coger únicamente los caracteres que aparecen por primera vez (el método `indexOf` sobre el carácter devuelve el índice actual: `first.indexOf(c) === i`) y que se encuentran en todas las palabras del array (utiliza `every` para comprobar que todos los elementos del array cumplen la condición de que contienen el carácter: `x.indexOf(c) >=0`.

Comment: muchas gracias desconocía tales funciones